# Show Database Table Data In JQuery

Tags: jquery, web-services

I Want to Display Database Table In My JSP Page. I Am Using JQuery And Web Services to this.

Can Any one Give me an example for this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would Suggest you to use jQuery [dataTables Plugin](http://datatables.net/)

> DataTables is a plug-in for the jQuery Javascript library. It is a
>   highly flexible tool, based upon the foundations of progressive
>   enhancement, which will add advanced interaction controls to any HTML
>   table.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest my own griffin.table plugin: https://github.com/jgauffin/Griffin.Table

The JSON formats (used in the ajax requests) are specified here: https://github.com/jgauffin/Griffin.Table/wiki/Request---response-format